# For Atom text editor, how can I create syntax / package for SystemOut.log for WebSphere Application Server?

Tags: syntax, atom-editor

I recently started using Atom text editor and it is really good! I love it so far.

I was working on the project with WebSphere Application Server and I noticed Atom shows SystemOut.log (the log file) as a plain text (all same text color). I searched package list but there is no package for it I think.

I am thinking of creating the package for it but I am not sure how. I wonder there is a package OR please tell me the document / link to find how to create the package for my case.

The example of the log is following:

```
[11/3/16 12:02:12:593 GMT] 00000001 ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0017I: The startup trace state is *=info.
[11/3/16 12:02:12:594 GMT] 00000001 ManagerAdmin  E   TRAS0111I: The message IDs that are in use are deprecated
```

That E indicates error and I just want to change color of it. So I can easily find error messages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounded like something I could use so I went ahead and created it.

My file structure for the package looks like this:

[image: Structure]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "language-was-log",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Syntax highlighting for WebSphere SystemOut Logs",
  "engines": {
    "atom": "*"    
  }
}
```

was-log.cson

```
'scopeName': 'text.waslog'
'name': 'WebSphere Log'
'fileTypes': ['log']
'patterns': [
  {
        'match': '.{45,55}( O ).*'
        'name': 'stylegreen'
  },
  {
        'match': '.{45,55}( E ).*'
        'name': 'stylered'
  }
]
```

styles.less

```
atom-text-editor::shadow {
    .stylered {
      color: red;
    }
    .stylegreen {
      color: green;
    }
}
```

Once you have this, create a symlink from your package to the atom packages folder:

```
$ cd ~/.atom/packages
$ ln -nsf {package location}/language-was-log
```

Then in atom, [cmd]-[shift]-[p] to bring up command pallette and execute Window: Reload